# Unrecht/kein Recht/nicht recht haben

Tags: usage

> You are wrong.

According to [this dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/unrecht), this sentence can be translated as

> (a) Du hast unrecht.

(I followed Duden's [recommendation](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unrecht) and didn't capitalize "unrecht".)

Can it also be translated as

> (b) Du hast kein recht.

or

> (c) Du hast nicht recht.

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sentences (a) and (c) are right.

> Du hast kein **R**echt, …

translates to *you don't have the right to …*, but note that *Recht* must be capitalized in that case.

Nevertheless, there is a similar expression meaning *you are wrong*:

> Du bist im Unrecht.
>   Du bist nicht im Recht.

These are rather formal.